# What does "Error code 1" mean when upgrading Firefox port?

Tags: freebsd, firefox, bsd-ports

I have several of these errors while trying to upgrade Firefox.  I have updated my ports.

Here are the last few lines of Firefox install:

```
===>   Registering installation for py27-setuptools27-5.5.1_1 as automatic
Installing py27-setuptools27-5.5.1_1...
pkg-static: py27-setuptools27-5.5.1_1 conflicts with py27-setuptools-1.1.7_1 (installs files into the same place).
    Problematic file: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth.dist
*** [fake-pkg] Error code 70

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/py-setuptools27.
*** [build-depends] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/py-Jinja2.
*** [install] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/py-Jinja2.
*** [build-depends] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/textproc/py-sphinx.
*** [build-depends] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/llvm34.
*** [install] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/llvm34.
*** [build-depends] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/lang/clang34.
*** [install] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/lang/clang34.
*** [build-depends] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/www/firefox.
*** [install] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/www/firefox.
->
```

Comment: [See if this helps](http://blog.khmersite.net/2013/10/upgrade-existing-perl-5-12-to-perl-5-18-on-freebsd-9/)

Comment: Specifically the note about [Python 2.6 to Python 2.7 from 20110304](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/UPDATING?revision=379538&view=markup#l7065), I assume.

Comment: Or, more likely, the one from [20140307 about py-setuptools](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/UPDATING?revision=379538&view=markup#l1813)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions in [`/usr/ports/UPDATING`](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/UPDATING?revision=379538&view=markup#l1813) from 20140307:

```
20140307:
  AFFECTS: users of devel/py-setuptools dependent ports
  AUTHOR: sunpoet@FreeBSD.org

  [...]

  Please rebuild all ports that depend on devel/py-setuptools and use 
  devel/py-setuptools{27,32,33} instead.

  XX represents python version (27, 32 or 33) in the following steps.

  pkgng users:

  # pkg set -o devel/py-setuptools:devel/py-setuptoolsXX

  portmaster users:

  # portmaster -o devel/py-setuptoolsXX devel/py-setuptools
  # portmaster -r py\*setuptools

  portupgrade users:

  # portupgrade -o devel/py-setuptoolsXX -f devel/py-setuptools
  # portupgrade -fr devel/py-setuptools
```

References:

- [FreeBSD Bugzilla Bug 187329 - devel/py-setuptools27 fails to install](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=187329)
- [FreeBSD forums - py27-setuptools27 doesn't compile](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/py27-setuptools27-doesnt-compile.45741/)